# Impala query: return only first x characters from a desired column

Tags: sql, impala

Is it possible to have a query only return the first 100 characters of a field?

For example, my original query is:

```
select text from my_table
```

But now I only want the first 100 characters in the column 'text', is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: use the `substring` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Strleft(text,100) from my_table
```

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_string_functions.html

Comment: I tried above, but got the error: OperationalError: Operation is in ERROR_STATE   any idea?